# Проверить, что строка содержит время в часах и минутах

Tags: c#, валидация

Как правильно проверить строку чтобы она соответствовала "hh:mm" ?

Например чтобы "01:15" - true, "1:15" - false, "" - false и тд

Comment: `Regex.IsMatch(t, @"\d{2}:\d{2}")` например

Comment: А почему `"1:15" - false`? Ведь это валидное время. В современном C# вон даже для времени есть специальные классы, где вы можете сделать `TimeOnly.TryParse("1:15", out var result)`, выдаст вам в итоге `true` или `false`, а в `result` будет сам объект `TimeOnly`, с которым дальше и работайте. Тоже самое можете через `TimeSpan` сделать.

Comment: `TimeSpan.TryParseExact(value, "hh\\:mm", null, out TimeSpan _)`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если строго, то невалидное. Отсутствие лидирующего нуля у часов означает 12-часовой формат времени, после которого должно следовать am/pm. Но это конечно не отменяет никак вами сказанного.